# Breaking the paragraph to up, not down CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there any possibility to make a `<br>` to break paragraph up, not down?

```
<p class="paragraph">world<br>hello</p>
```

Comment: So that hello would come before world?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You could split the paragraph into divs, set `display: div` to the parent and adjust the positions with `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-areas` and `grid-area`s.

Comment: Does orientation matter? `transform: rotate(180deg);`

Comment: What is your usecase?

Comment: I want to create a console log that is getting filled when button is clicked. So every time a button is clicked, an event listener will add a content to the paragraph, after a <br>.

Comment: @BadControlHypnos It would be easier to prepend the content instead of appending.

Comment: Or `display: div` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` to the parent while splitting the content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

splitting them into two paragraphs

and wrapping them in a **div** with
`display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

In the snippet I made two copies and gave one of them a small width to see the wrap effect.

Check the snippet:

```css
p{
  margin: 0;
}
.container1{
  /*width: 30px;*/
  display: flex;
  gap: .2rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
.container2{
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  gap: .2rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
</div>
```